# get error msg "TypeError: childPath.split is not a function" when trying to delete images from firebase storage in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a DataGrid (mui) table where each row shows the various fields of a firestore document, including images. On clicking a delete button, first a confirmation popup appears and on clicking 'yes', the document is deleted from the collection. I want to also delete the images from firebase storage. However, so far I have to click twice on the button for this to happen. The first click brings up this msg in the console :

> "Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: childPath.split is not a function. (In 'childPath.split('/')', 'childPath.split' is undefined)"

The second click **does** delete the image but also brings up

> "Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'docSnap.data().image')"

I can't figure out the first error, nor why it works on the second click. Here's my code. Any help would be much appreciated

**firebase queries**

```
import { collection, getDocs, addDoc, updateDoc, deleteDoc, doc, query, where, getDoc, orderBy} from 'firebase/firestore'
    
    const rapportsPassagesCollectionRef = collection(db,'rapportsPassages')
    
    class RapportsPassagesDataService {
    
        deleteRapportPassage = (id) => {
            const rapportPassageDoc = doc(db,"rapportsPassages",id) 
            return deleteDoc(rapportPassageDoc)
        }
    
        getRapportsPassages = () => {
            const rapportsByDate = query (rapportsPassagesCollectionRef,orderBy("date","asc"))
            return getDocs(rapportsByDate)
        }
    
        getRapportPassage = (id) => {
            const rapportPassageDoc = doc(db,"rapportsPassages",id)
            return getDoc(rapportPassageDoc) 
        }
    
    }
    
    export default new RapportsPassagesDataService()
```

**file containing logic to delete images**

```
const [rapports, setRapports] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getRapports()
    }, [])

    const getRapports = async () => {
        const data = await RapportsPassagesDataService.getRapportsPassages()
        setRapports(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id:  doc.id })))
    }


const [images, setImages] = useState([])
    


const findImages = async (id) => {
   if (id !== undefined && id !== "") {
     const docSnap = await RapportsPassagesDataService.getRapportPassage(id)
     setImages(docSnap.data().image)
   }
 }
    


 const photos = images.toString()

    const photoName = (photos.substring(69, photos.length - 53));


    const deleteImages = () => {
        const storageRef = ref(storage,'/' + photoName)

        deleteObject(storageRef).then(() => {
            console.log('success');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

    }


const handleDelete = (id) => {
    
    confirmAlert({
           title: 'Confirm',
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this document ?',
            buttons: [
                  {
                    label: 'Yes',
                    onClick: async () => {
                    findImages(id)
                    deleteImages()
                    await RapportsPassagesDataService.deleteRapportPassage(id)
                    getRapports()
                    }
                   },
                    {
                      label: 'No',
    
                    }
                  ]
            })
    }
    
    
    

const actionColumn = [{
      field: "action",
       headerName: "",
       width: 150,
       renderCell: (params) => {
          return (
              <div className='cellAction'>
               <button className="deleteButton" 
                    onClick={() =>handleDelete(params.row.id)}>
               </buton>   
              </div>
           )
         }
        }]
```

I have edited my code and stringified `images`, substracted the image name such as I see it in `firebase storage`. However I still have to click the delete button twice to actually delete the image and the first click brings the following in the console.

"FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The operation 'deleteObject' cannot be performed on a root reference, create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png')"`

I am not too sure how to create a non-root reference as shown in the message. Nor do I understand why it works after 2 clicks.

Comment: There is no `childPath` in the code you've shared. Chances are, `childPath` is not a string.

Comment: When I get an error like this, I find it best to set a breakpoint on all relevant lines in my code, run in a debugger, and then step through the code line by line, and check the value of each variable on each line. When you do this, what is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: theres some code missing getRapports for example, also it would be beneficial to see the full component that wraps the the useState([]) for images. i see youve got an async method directly within that component, which is atypical for react.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The line where it seems to go wrong is `const storageRef = ref(storage,'/' + photoName)`in the `deleteImages` function. I've read the documentation [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files?hl=en) but haven't been able to apply it to my project

Comment: @MattPengelly I've added the bit of code for the `getRapports `function.  Not sure what you mean by "the full component that wraps the useState([]) for images". Do you mean the code that uploads the images ?

Comment: presumably, the code youve pasted exists within an a component? Thats what i mean. right now youve posted the contents of the component. but not the component itself. 

regardless, try and find where .split() is called and post that, if it isnt within your code then it must be within some code youre calling in a third party library